# Remove initial message: "In the vue 3 project, The Vue Language Features (Volar) is new recommended extension in VSCode.: "

Tags: neovim

I installed via mason `vetur-vls` and after opening any `*.vue` file, I got this message:

```
In the vue 3 project, The Vue Language Features (Volar) is new recommended extension in VSCode.: 
1: Learn More 
Type number and <Enter> or click with the mouse (q or empty cancels):
```

Any idea how to remove it?

I am using mason-lspconfig and detects/loads `vuels`